# How to concat data in the array in PHPExcel report

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpexcel

basically i want to concat my array to combine to POST(values) in generating PHPexcel report in excel but sadly i cant make it work...can anyone help me with this please.

heres the picture of the outcome today: i want it to become `"Buenavista, Agusan del Norte"`
http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/concat_zps4fad0536.png.html

current code in my array:

```
"'$town''.,&nbsp;.''$region'",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just this:

```
"$town,  $region"
```

Answer (score 1):

Either decode them using `html_entity_decode` or remove them using `preg_replace`:

```
$data = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i","",$data);
```

Hope it helps you